# How can I set a timeout on a Tornado HTTP request?

Tags: python, httprequest, tornado

I am using the Tornado async HTTP client. I want to raise an exception if the request takes more than X milliseconds. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you using any library to make the HTTP request?

Comment: @LutzHorn yes the Tornado AsyncHTTPClient

Comment: `HTTPRequest` has timeout options: https://tornado.readthedocs.io/en/latest/httpclient.html#tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`request_timeout`](https://tornado.readthedocs.io/en/latest/httpclient.html#tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest) argument, which defaults to 20 seconds (floating point numbers are accepted, so you can use e.g. 0.1 for 100ms).

Answer (score 1):

from the Tornado docs:

http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpclient.html#request-objects

Use these named parameters in `tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest` or in `AsyncHTTPClient.fetch`

> connect_timeout (float) – Timeout for initial connection in seconds
>
> request_timeout (float) – Timeout for entire request in seconds

Since they are floats, you should be able to specify the timeout in milliseconds, e.g. .1 will be 100 milliseconds